# How to rewrite this without duplication, using Standard SQL BIG Query syntax?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Merging two tables the time entries table onto the user's table.  Currently using Big query standard SQL. The column id is supposed to have 1 unique id for each entry but yet it pulls multiple of the same id # My Question how to rewrite this query without receiving duplications in the results? How to use LEFT Join with UNION ALL or UNION DISTINCT?

```
--*** Gives Duplications for some reason *** 
SELECT outer_e.hours, outer_e.id, outer_e.updated_at, outer_e.spent_date, u.first_name, u.is_active, u.id AS user_id, u.weekly_capacity FROM
  (SELECT e.id, MAX(e.updated_at) AS updated_at FROM `harvest-experiment.harvest.time_entries` AS e
  GROUP BY e.id LIMIT 1000) AS inner_e
LEFT JOIN `harvest-experiment.harvest.time_entries` AS outer_e
ON inner_e.id = outer_e.id AND inner_e.updated_at = outer_e.updated_at
LEFT JOIN `harvest-experiment.harvest.users` AS u
ON outer_e.user_id = u.id
```

Comment: thank you for sharing! you forgot to formulate the question :o) also - in case if you will - check [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the `DISTANT` Keyword next my SELECT keyword, by doing so seems to fix the duplication problem in the views.

```
__***** Current Solution *****———
--*** Returns a Left Joined Table of `time entries` and `users` *** 
SELECT DISTINCT outer_e.hours, outer_e.id, outer_e.updated_at, outer_e.spent_date, outer_e.created_at, outer_e.client_id, u.is_admin, u.first_name, u.is_active, u.id AS user_id, u.weekly_capacity, client.name FROM
  (SELECT  e.id, MAX(e.updated_at) AS updated_at FROM `harvest-experiment.harvest.time_entries` AS e 
  GROUP BY e.id LIMIT 1000) AS inner_e
LEFT JOIN `harvest-experiment.harvest.time_entries` AS outer_e
ON inner_e.id = outer_e.id AND inner_e.updated_at = outer_e.updated_at
LEFT JOIN `harvest-experiment.harvest.users` AS u
ON outer_e.user_id = u.id
```